# How to close a Kendo window from within the window content?

Tags: kendo-ui, window

I have an application. In a button clicked I tried to open a Kendo modal window. It's opening. My application is in one domain and the content of the Kendo window is from another domain. Now I want to close the modal window with a button which is inside the Kendo window. Here the issue begins. I cannot close the modal window. I searched using Google it but did not find any solution — do you know one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading your comments to my previous answer I think that you question is misleading. You talk about `modal`, *another domain* and `close` `button` but seems from your comments that nothing of that is actually relevant. I conclude from your comments that you want to place a `button` (actually a `close` `button` but might be any other) in a KendoUI `window` and in addition you want to display a page (that incidentally) is in a different domain. If this is what you actually want -and foreseeing problem related to cross-domain and security- I would recommend that you should actually use `content.template` and define a template including your `button` and an `iframe` referencing the page `www.xyz.com`.

Something like this...

```
var myWindow2 = $("#id2").kendoWindow({
    modal    : true,
    draggable: false,
    content  : {
        template: '<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="close2" class="k-button">Close</a>' +
                '<iframe src="http://www.xyz.com" frameborder="0" class="k-content-frame"></iframe>'
    },
    visible  : false,
    width    : 400,
    height   : 200,
    resizable: false,
    iframe   : true
}).data("kendoWindow");

$("#open2").on("click", function () {
    myWindow2.center();
    myWindow2.open();
});

$("#close2").on("click", function () {
    myWindow2.close();
});
```

You might even make the button `float` on top of the rest of the page by defining the following style for `close` `button`.

```
#close2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

Comment: Dear Onabari thank you so much for your reply. I understood that close button (in the kendo window content) could not close the window. I have to make the close button in the client side kendo window (on the top or bottom) not in the content of the kendo window. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 2):

The following JavaScript code defines a `button` for opening a `modal` `kendoWindow`. Once clicked you can press a `button` inside the body of the `window` for closing it as you want.

JavaScript code:

```
var myWindow = $("#id1").kendoWindow({
    title  : "hi",
    visible: false,
    modal  : true
}).data("kendoWindow");

$("#open").on("click", function () {
    console.log("opening");
    myWindow.center();
    myWindow.open();
});
$("#close").on("click", function () {
    console.log("closing");
    myWindow.close();
})
```

and the `HTML`:

```
<a href="#" id="open" class="k-button">Open</a>

<div id="id1">
    <p>this is the content of my window</p>
    <a href="#" id="close" class="k-button">Close</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Very much for your answer OnaBari. But this is not the actual solution of my issue. The content of the modal is coming from another domain. and the close button will be inside the content. Now how to close this modal window by clicking the button. If it is same domain no problem occurs. But the parent page and the modal window are in different domain.

Comment: How are you loading the content, `iframe` perhaps?

Comment: window.kendoWindow({
        modal: true,
        animation: false,
        draggable: false,
        content: 'http://www.xxxx.com'

        width: "830px",
        height: "650px",        
        resizable: false,
        //title:false,
        visible: false
    }).data("kendoWindow").title(Title).center().open();

Comment: According KendoUI documentation (see [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/window#content-objectstring) ) KendoUI will introduce an `iframe` for displaying the page. If that's your case (and I think so) you will have serious limitation from inside another web-page access data of the container (and those problems depend on the browser -same origin policy-).

Comment: Check that KendoUI does not use an `iframe` for displaying the content of the `window`. If so, you should be able to use the proposed solution declaring `myWindow` as global to the document (i.e. outside the `$(document).ready(function () {...})` and leave definition inside as it is).

Comment: Thank you so much. But as you see content of the kendo window is coming from another domain. Actually an website is showing in that kendo window. Now in the that web site i have a button. Now can the websits's button closed the kendo window which is called form another website?

Comment: Say i have a website www.abc.com and there is a button by which a kendo window opens. Now the content of the kendo window holds another website say www.xyz.com, now can we close the kendo window by a button which is present www.xyz.com website. Plz help our project got stuck over here.